# How to change language in Skype

Tags: skype, languages, user-interface

I installed Skype on my Samsung Galaxy Tab, and need change default English language.

How to change Skype Tablet **interface** language from English to other (French, for example)?

Answer (score 1):

Skype for Android uses your tablet's default language. From their [support site](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12084/in-what-languages-is-skype-for-android-available?frompage=search&q=in%20what%20languages%20is%20skype%20for%20android%20availabl%27&fromSearchFirstPage=false):

> Skype for Android is currently available in [32 different] languages (based on your phone’s or tablet’s language setting).

What language is your tablet set to? To check (or to change it) go to `Settings > Language & input`. It does not look possible to change the language used by Skype without changing it for the whole tablet.

Answer (score -1):

there is actually a way to do so, make sure that the source file your downloaded sourcefile is in the language you requested, ie downloading Skype_3.1.0.6458 in your case

Comment: This is about an Android app, not downloading the Skype app for Windows.

Answer (score -2):

- Does not exist yet the only way is to decompile the application
- Then change each line written in .apk/res/
- The folders i found in resources of skype app

  anim   drawable       drawable-hdpi-v11  drawable-land       drawable-land-ldpi
  drawable-ldpi     drawable-mdpi      drawable-mdpi-v9  drawable-port       drawable-
  port-ldpi  drawable-xhdpi      drawable-xhdpi-v9  layout-land  menu      raw
  color  drawable-hdpi  drawable-hdpi-v9   drawable-land-hdpi  drawable-land-mdpi  drawable-
  ldpi-v9  drawable-mdpi-v11  drawable-nodpi    drawable-port-hdpi  drawable-port-mdpi
  drawable-xhdpi-v11  layout             layout-port  menu-v11  xml
- or try sending them an email at: skypeuploader@googlemail.com